# Database engine for high intensive write

Tags: database, cassandra, rocksdb

I want to write hundreds of GB into database server each day (only at free time, for example, at night). Also I want that data is only available after written is done. For example, if you use a RDBMS system, you will write to temporary table and then swap between new and old table.

That's the reason why I want to have a database support for intensive write. There are some options that I have researched.

- RocksDB: suitable for write, but because this is embedded database so there is no good tool for monitoring.
- Cassandra: I think it is too overkill.

There is some other databases I have researched: CockroachDB and HBase. So which database suitable for my high write intensive with easily management purpose.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this question is better suited for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Apart from that, Cassandra performs quite well with many inserts when you have a look on async inserts and batches that hit only one node. We do this every day with >100GB of data.

Keep in mind that you will need a strategy to get rid of old data in any database you choose. One thing cassandra can't handle for you is a "huge" transaction that makes the data visible after the complete inserts done. You have to do this on application side - we use a "marker insert" for this and only do processing in clients when the marker was set already.

Also some guys at Instagram combinded RocksDB and Cassandra to Rocksandra:

https://github.com/Instagram/cassandra/tree/rocks_3.0
https://instagram-engineering.com/open-sourcing-a-10x-reduction-in-apache-cassandra-tail-latency-d64f86b43589

Answer (score 0):

You can try scylla and cassandra both for high writes. Cassandra provides good flexibility and scalability with lots of features. you can refer apache.org or datastax cassandra for more details. Scylla is also good option if you want to achieve good performance as written in C++.